# Invariant forms of a binary quintic

Tags: invariant-theory

Does anyone have a reference for the invariant binary forms of a quintic? That is, what are the $SL_2(C)$ invariant polynomial functions on the space of binary quintics.

Comment: Complementing Noam's answer: for $d\leq 6$ the algebras of $SL_2$-invariants of degree $d$ forms in 2 variables can be found in 10.2 of Dolgachev's Lectures on invariant theory, as well as a reference in English for $d=5$.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this page](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/math/invar.html) there are independent invariants of degree 4, 8, and 12, plus a degree-18 invariant whose square is a polynomial in the first three.  This is attributed to Gordan (1868):

> P. Gordan, Beweis, dass jede Covariante und Invariante einer binären Form eine ganze Funktion mit numerischen Coeffizienten einer endlichen Anzahl solcher Formen ist, *Journ. f. Math.* **69** (1868), 323–354.

That page also describes the invariants, and even the covariants, for several other degrees, and also variations such as multiple forms.

[All I did was [Google it](http://www.google.com/search?q=invariants+of+binary+quintic); the present MO question already turned up in the first page of search results only a few hours after it was posted.]

Comment: The complete list of invariants was discovered by Hermite in "Sur la theorie des fonctions homogenes a deux indeterminees" Cambridge and Dublin Mathematical Journal, vol 9, pp. 172-217, 1854. Gordan discovered the larger list of covariants. Perhaps the quickest justification of the list of invariants is using the Sylvester canonical form ax^5+by^5-c^(x+y)^5 and writing the invariants in terms of a, b, c. It is done for instance in Salmon's higher algebra book.